# Check if user can in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest-api, wp-api, backbone

Using the rest API I retrieve a collection of posts:

```js
const recordsParams = {}
const recordsCollection = new wp.api.collections.MyPostType();
recordsCollection.fetch( { data: recordsParams } )
    .then( records => {
        this.records = records
    } ).catch( error => {
    console.log( error );
} )
```

I then loop on each retrieved post and I need an equivalent to the PHP's `<?php current_user_can('edit_myposttype', $post_id); ?>` in order to check if the current user can edit each post and act accordingly.

Is there something equivalent in the WordPress JavaScript API ?

I found a `canUser(state, action, resource, id)` function in `core-data.js`, but I can't get how to invoke and use it.

Or is there any other way to achive my goal ?

Comment: The best way I think would be to extend the existing REST call you're making to return you an editable flag for each post, rather than making a separate call, but I don't know the JavaScript end of these APIs to know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am doing already, but was wondering if there was a proper way to do it using the WP Api ...